# DRopbox API - Best/Fastest way to get a link to an image

Tags: api, directory, dropbox-api

My code is attempting to retrieve images and display them.  I have code that uses the Dropbox API code, it calls searchFileNames("/My Photos", ".jpg",  50, false), so it returns at least 50 results.  I need to get the width & height, so for each of the returned items, I then need to call getMetadata() to retrieve that information, so far so good.  Now I need a link to the image file that I can use to initially display a thumbnail.  I get 50 results back so I need to do something 50 times, such as createShareableLink() or createTemporaryDirectLink() - my issue is that this takes TOO LONG.  My tests for 50 items run somewhere close to a FULL minute - TOO SLOW. I could look at getFile() but that's about the same minute range.   Maybe another API call where I get the link back in one call that  is FASTER?  Looking for a faster way to get a direct link to an image in a Dropbox Folder?  Any help is appreciated - Thanks

Answer (score 2):

These are the steps that I take to get a link to an image:

- https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload

  - response
  - get and store the `path_display` response from the json
- https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/sharing/create_shared_link_with_settings

  - request
  - set the `path` param to `path_display` from upload call
  - set `settings` to `{ requested_visibility:"public"}`
  - response
  - You get back `url` parameter, this is the share link. If you give this to someone they will end up on the dropbox page
  - If you append to `url` `&raw=1` (maybe `?raw=1`) then with that link users will end up directly on the image, rather then on a dropbox page. This is useful for embeding into `<img>` `src` attribute.

Comment: Yep - I use that now "2/sharing/create_shared_link", I cal it 50 times with the "path" or "id".  This is what takes a bit over a second for each call totaling over a minute before I return with any results...  I guess I could cut my expected results in half, so my users only wait about 25 second for the screen to start showing results - not ideal...

Comment: The getMetadata() also takes some time, I call this to get the width & height of the image I'm trying to display...

Comment: I agree with you, there should be a parameter to the post, on upload, so I can get a shared link back in just one query.

Comment: Noitidart yes!!! Maybe some input params that allow me to ask for the width, height and sharableLink when I perform the searchFileNames() in the first place, so I don't have to make the 2 additional calls.  In any case, the 2 additional calls take too long to complete for my purposes, and probably for others as well trying to accomplish what I'm trying to do.